# Wait for jQueryUI Popup for continue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jQueryUI to make a confirmation popup to save. I am writing a finishing function for when the user is done editing everything. The popup comes up and the rest of the finishing function goes on before the confirmation is selected "don't save" "save" or "cancel". I am using the confirmation several times, so I can't change that specifically for this instance.
How do I make the function wait for the results of the confirmation?

```
    $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    title: 'Save Changes',
    buttons: {
        "Don't Save": function() {
            setDivText();
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        },
        Cancel: function(){
            $("#selection option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
            $.each($("#selection option"), function(){
                if($(this).val() == prevSel){
                    $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
                }
            });
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        "Save": function(){
            organizedDivs[prevSel][2] = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();
            setDivText();
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    }
});
```

and

```
function output(){
if(tinyMCE.activeEditor.isDirty()){
    $("#dialog").dialog('open'); 
    saveAll();
} else {
    saveAll();
}
}
```

and

```
function saveAll(){
$.each( fileText.match( /<div.*?class=".*?editable.*?".*?>[\s\S.]*?<.div>/g ), function( index, value ){
    value.replace(/(id=".*?".*?>)([.\s\S]*?)(<.div>)/ ,"$1" + organizedDivs[index][2] + "$3"); 
});
}
```

Comment: I've decided that keeping the original text clean is pointless and I could make incremental updates directly to the text so when the 'finish' is called, the same incremental save is called. If there is a solution to make the code wait, I would still be interested in the solution to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

==== UPDATED answer:

OK, I admit that this is a ugly solution, since what I know for 'halting' the javascript program is: alert(), confirm(), and sometimes $.ajax({async:false}).  :

so my solution is simply re-implement the code by adding the "saveAll()" to the end of each callback function:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({ autoOpen: false, modal: true, title: 'Save Changes',
buttons: {
    "Don't Save": function() {
        setDivText();
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        saveAll();       // newly added line of code       
    },
   "Cancle": function(){
        //....
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        saveAll();       // newly added line of code       
    },
   "Save": function(){
        //....
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        saveAll();       // newly added line of code       
    }
 // other code...
}

// and in your "finishing function"
function output(){
  if(tinyMCE.activeEditor.isDirty()){
    $("#dialog").dialog('open'); 
    // this line of code : saveAll() was removed from here. 
  }else{
    saveAll();
  }
}
```

Comment: That was separated like that in several different attempts to get it to work. I'm afraid I'm fairly new to jQuery and do not know how to set async to false. I've looked in the jQueryUI documentation and jQuery website and have looked over the ajax stuff, but it's asking for a url. I just want a function.

Comment: OK, I read your post again and for this sentense: `How do I make the function wait for the results of the confirmation?`  could you please show us what it( here the 'it' is the finishing function, which should be halt as you expect when the dialog is open) looks like?

Comment: 'it'? umm, I want saveAll() to wait until the $("#dialog").dialog is closed.

Comment: be honest, the saveAll() function doesn't quite work right either, but I'm trying to fix one thing at a time.

Comment: got it, thanks for your reply, now I got your point.  check my updated answer. (my code is written on the fly and not tested)

Comment: I was afraid I would have to re implement the dialog. I don't much like redundant code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just put your what your want to do (like `saveAll();`) in the callback function.

Like:

```
"Save": function(){
            organizedDivs[prevSel][2] = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();
            setDivText();
            saveAll();
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
```

Comment: The finishing save isn't part of the dialog. I was keeping them separate because the dialog is called any time the section content has been changed and moved to another section. The saveAll compiles the sections into one final product.  I just want to make sure the organizedDivs have the updated content (if the user accepts) before compiling the final product.